# What is the right viscosity of silicone grease for ceramic-discs in mixer faucet?

Tags: plumbing, silicone

[image]

Hi.

What is the right viscosity of a silicone grease to lubricate between the ceramic-discs of single lever mixer faucet?
NLGI-00,NLGI 1,NLGI 2 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the manufacturer's documentation on what the proper product to use is?  That would be my starting point.

Comment: No,unfortunately,i couldn't achieve the manufacturer's documentation.I would like to know,in general,what should the viscosity be,when applying it between ceramic-discs?It doesn't matter which company made it.ceramic-discs made of ceramic in all brands.The question is what is the viscosity of the grease that should use in ceramic disc?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to understand your post; would you spend a little time fixing capitalization and sentences, and splitting it into a paragraph or two? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to break open that unit and **"lubricate between the ceramic-discs that are located inside the plastic cartridge of a single lever mixer faucet."** ?  I would assume that if the manufacturer wanted you to do that they would have given you the instruction and  info to do it. ?  *Potable or Portable ?*

Comment: Silicone grease is silicone grease, if there were a special requirement, the manufacturer's documents and/or website would be the place to look. Some brands even use Teflon lubricants... the only thing that usually matters, is that it be an approved food grade lubricant.

Comment: When the handle of a mixer faucet becomes stiff,it usually because the grease between the ceramic discs washed-off and relubricate them solve the issue.You are all should know that(if you expert in that area).You can find alot of videos and sites how it's done,but they don't mention the viscosity of the grease.The viscosity of a silicone grease is important.Silicone grease isn't just silicone grease as lithium grease isn't just lithium grease.When you apply lithium grease to wheel bearing of a car you use NLGI-2 viscosity,so it's important.Can i get,please,an answer from a professional.

Comment: @xchcui “*When the handle of a mixer faucet becomes stiff,it usually because the grease between the ceramic discs washed-off and relubricate them solve the issue”* did a **professional** tell you that ?  If you want advice from a professional then you should call a professional.   I have never heard of anybody breaking open a sealed cartridge to lubricate the ceramic discs so if a professional tells you it’s possible then listen to the professional. **If I were you I would call the manufacturer**.

Comment: I have never heard of this.  As far as I know, ceramic discs last a long time.  I have never had to do this on any of my taps.  The last time, a tap (disc/valve) failed was 2 months ago.  And the importer replaced it with a different tap, under warranty.  he had stopped importing the one we had because of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The spec sheet for Molykote 7508 valve grease says viscosity is 30,000 to 85,000 mPas